# How to using ORDER BY and LIMIT in UNION mysql query

Tags: mysql, union

i have a litte problem, i have a MySQL query code like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.name AS itemName, b.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_product b ON b.id = a.targetid AND a.target='PRODUCT'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
UNION
SELECT a.id, c.name AS itemName, c.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_news c ON c.id = a.targetid AND a.target='NEWS'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
UNION
SELECT a.id, d.name AS itemName, d.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_promo d ON d.id = a.targetid AND a.target='PROMO'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
```

How to add `ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0,10` in query above? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your intensions are to `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` each query befor the `UNION`, Just add

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

At the bottom of the query.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it with another select.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.id, b.name AS itemName, b.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_product b ON b.id = a.targetid AND a.target='PRODUCT'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
UNION
SELECT a.id, c.name AS itemName, c.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_news c ON c.id = a.targetid AND a.target='NEWS'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
UNION
SELECT a.id, d.name AS itemName, d.slug AS itemSlug FROM table_idx a
INNER JOIN table_promo d ON d.id = a.targetid AND a.target='PROMO'
WHERE a.memberid=$memberid
) AS t ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: What are the performance consequences of something like this versus not having a limit assuming the result set is really small?